# ng-show not working on bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs

**HTML** :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_initial"  tabindex="-1"    
     ng-show="myModal" data-backdrop="static" role="dialog"></div>
```

**JS** :

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.myModal = true;

});
```

on setting `$scope.myModal = true`, still unable to find modal getting opened.

Comment: Use angular-ui-bootstrap instead of the jquery-based bootstrap library.

Answer (score -1):

Check Bootstrap modal from w3schools.com. It is explained clearly.
Example to trigger the model

The "Trigger" part:

To trigger the modal window, you need to use a button or a link.

Then include the two data-* attributes:

data-toggle = "modal" opens the modal window
data-target = "#myModal" points to the id of the modal